# spring mvc не удается отобразить jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**структура папок**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**orderController.java**

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping("/order")
    public class OrderController {

        @RequestMapping(value="createDB")
       public String createDB(ModelMap model) {

            model.addAttribute("message", "Database has been created");
            return "tables";

        }
             ...

     }
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.CoinsShop" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**tables.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

использую плагин tomcat для тестирования

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                <server>localhost</server>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>shop</finalName>
</build>
```

при запросе на http://localhost:8080/shop/order/createDB вместо tables.jsp выводится пустое окно

Comment: Если смотреть на скрин, то файл у вас называется `tables`, а не `tables.jsp` как должно бы быть.

Comment: просто расширение не отображается

Comment: Тогда смотрите дебаг.